# How to insert the square number symbol (small 2) in vim?

Tags: insert-mode

I need in vim input the following Numbers:

> 23²,66²,38³

How to insert this number?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way is probably to copy and paste those numbers into Vim. That should just work. Alternatively, if you want to write down those, you can use the digraph feature like this: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>K</kbd><kbd>2</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>

See the help at `:h digraphs` and `:h 24.9`